# Undefined local variable or method `destroy_posts_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when I want create a link which destroy article, browser show me an error

```
undefined local variable or method `destroy_posts_path'
```

This is my action destroy in controller Posts

```
   def destroy
       @posts = Posts.find(params[:id])
       @posts.destroy

         redirect_to posts_path
   end
```

and this is my routes.rb

```
  resources :posts
```

this is string from html

```
  <td><%= link_to 'Del', destroy_posts_path %></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like

```
<%= link_to 'Del', post_path(@post), :method => :delete %>
```

The named route should be `post_path` with method `delete` instead of `destroy_posts_path`. Also you need to pass in the object or id of the object you want to delete

When you look at the output of `rake routes`, you will see something like

```
 DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"posts"}
```

Comment: Thank you, it half-working, but i want to know why it not work how in railsguides.Because when i adding 'new_posts_path' the same thing happens - browser show 'undefined local variable or method'

Comment: Where in rails guides do you see that you have to use `destroy_posts_path` for deleting the resource?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling to a route/path that doesn't exist. There is no such thing as `delete_posts_path`.

Try `<%= link_to "Del", post_path(@post), method: :delete %>` instead.

Comment: I need to write a rule for delete_posts_path in routes.rb?sorry for my bad English

Comment: No need to create another path. By sending a request to the posts_path with the method of :delete and passing in the exact post you are trying to delete, you are telling your controller to use the delete/destroy method and not the default :show method. So no need to add an additional path. Just use the link_to as written above. Hope this helps!

Comment: No problem! Glad it is working. new_posts_path wouldn't be a correct route either. it would be new_post_path as you are only creating one post (singular) not posts (plural). Here is a guide for routing in Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html